# how to change UITabBar appearance ins iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

With **iOS 6** I can customize `UITabBar` with this code:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(39/255.0) green:(205/255.0) blue:(222/255.0) alpha:1]];
```

But I can't with **iOS 7**. I am forced to use two type of picture to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
UIImage *tabBarBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CustomUITabbar.png"];
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:tabBarBackground];
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Taken from: http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/ios-custom-ui-series-tabbar-navbar/ by: https://twitter.com/robwhitlow3